# how to get multiple data from multiple queries using getelementbyid

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have getdata.php file that using multiple queries to get multiple data from mysql database.

==getdata.php==

```
<?php

$koneksi = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","gepinfodb");

$sql_topic1 = "SELECT concat(floor(SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `jamkerja` ))/3600),' hours ',floor(SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `jamkerja` ))/60)%60,' minutes ',SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `jamkerja` ))%60,' seconds') AS timeSum FROM tbjamkerja";
$result_topic1= mysqli_query($koneksi,$sql_topic1);
$row_topic1=mysqli_fetch_array($result_topic1,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo $row_topic1['timeSum'];



$sql_topic2 = "SELECT COUNT(nama) AS jumlahkaryawan FROM user";
$result_topic2= mysqli_query($koneksi,$sql_topic2);
$row_topic2=mysqli_fetch_array($result_topic2,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo $row_topic2['jumlahkaryawan'];



$sql_topic3 = "SELECT COUNT(distinct tgl) AS insidencedayfree FROM tbjamkerja";
$result_topic3= mysqli_query($koneksi,$sql_topic3);
$row_topic3=mysqli_fetch_array($result_topic3,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo $row_topic3['insidencedayfree'];


mysqli_close($koneksi);

?>
```

I get 3 row data from my database sql (timeSum, jumlahkaryawan, insidencedayfree) lets say the output is (1,2,3)

the index.php to show the data that I get from getdata.php.

==index.php==

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>LATIHAN</title>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="header">

            <div class="informasi">
            INFORMASI
            <div class="timeSum">
            <div class="jumlahkaryawan">
            <div class="insidencedayfree">
            </div>   

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function updateTime(){

  showUser();

}

$(function(){
  setInterval(updateTime, 2000);
});


function showUser(str) {
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {


document.getElementsByClassName('timeSum jumlahkaryawan insidencedayfree').innerHTML = this.responseText;


}
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?timeSum&jumlahkaryawan&insidencedayfree"+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}

</script>
```

the problem is, I can't get that 3 data (1,2,3) that I want to show in index.php using getElementsByClassName and the data did not separate to a unique class name. I tried using getelementbyId but the data is seems to be merge (like this 123)

what I want is, I want to get that 3 data to be fit in to different classes

example

```
class="timeSum" (the output is 1)  
class="jumlahkaryawan" (the output is 2) 
class="insidencedayfree" (the output is 3)
```

My skill is very basic. Also, pardon me if my english is bad. english is not my native languange. thanks for your guidance and help.

Comment: you are using `document.getElementsByClassName` incorrectly. `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a list of nodes that contains the classes you provide, instead of a sigle node. Hence you need to access it like array or iterate over it using a loop. for example `document.getElementsByClassName('timeSum jumlahkaryawan insidencedayfree')[0].innerHTML = this.responseText;`

Comment: @infdefurlong below answer works for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add some separtor in PHP output.

==getdata.php==

```
echo $row_topic1['timeSum'].",";

echo $row_topic2['jumlahkaryawan'].","; 

echo $row_topic3['insidencedayfree'];
```

==index.php==

Step 2: Split the value and set the value to each class separately.

```
    function showUser(str) {
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {

var phpOutput = this.responseText.split(',');
document.getElementsByClassName('timeSum')[0].innerHTML = phpOutput[0];
document.getElementsByClassName('jumlahkaryawan')[0].innerHTML = phpOutput[1];
document.getElementsByClassName('insidencedayfree')[0].innerHTML = phpOutput[2];


}
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?timeSum&jumlahkaryawan&insidencedayfree"+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
```

below link explain how to use the getbyclassname "[link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)"